# Fetching mySQL DATETIME value in C++

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2013

I cannot read a DATETIME value from a mySQL table using VS2013.
I'm using mysql-connector-1.1.9-win32 (mysqlcppconn.lib)

[this is the row containing the datas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHNjE.jpg)
Here is my code:

```
sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver* m_driver;
sql::Connection* m_conn;
sql::Statement* m_stmt;
sql::ResultSet* m_res;

m_driver = sql::mysql::get_driver_instance();
m_conn = m_driver->connect(ch_hostName, ch_userName, ch_pwd);

m_stmt = m_conn->createStatement();
m_res = m_stmt->executeQuery("select tip, id1, datum from recordLocker where id1 = 'A0001' and tip = 1");

try
{
  m_res->getString("datum");
}
catch (sql::SQLException& e)
{
  TRACE1("\nSQL Error  %d\n", e.getErrorCode());
}
```

I'm geting "SQL Error 0"
I also tried:

```
m_res->getInt64("datum");
m_res->getUInt64("datum");
```

with the same error code (m_res is not empty).

Thanks for helping!

Comment: `DATETIME` is neither a string, nor an integer value.

Comment: sql::ResultSet does not have a getDateTime() function, this is my problem

Answer (score 0):

I changed the connector to mysql-5.7.19-win32.
This connector returns all columns in string format, that can be converted ton integer, double, ... or CTime.

Here is my code:

```
MYSQL* m_sql; 
MYSQL* m_conn; 

mysql_init(m_sql)
m_conn = mysql_real_connect(m_sql, ch_Host, ch_User, ch_Pwd, ch_Db, 0, 0, 0);

mysql_query(m_conn, "select * from recordLocker");

MYSQL_RES* m_res = mysql_use_result(m_conn);

MYSQL_ROW m_row;

while( m_row = mysql_fetch_row(m_res))
{
  CString szDate = CString(mysqlRow[6]);
  //szDate is in the following format "YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000000"
}
```